Understanding std::convertible_to syntax
I am reading about concepts in c++20, and I am stuck on the following code snippet.
Specifically, line { value.get_hp() } -> std::convertible_to<unsigned int>;, I understand it says we can make call value.get_hp() for a variable value of type T, and its return value is convertible to unsigned int. But I do not understand the syntax here. What is the usage of -> in this line?
#include <concepts>
namespace contracts::cpp20
{
    template <typename T>
    concept can_behave = requires(T value)
    {
        value.behave();
    };

    template <typename T>
    concept has_hp_getter = requires(const T value)
    {
        { value.get_hp() } -> std::convertible_to<unsigned int>;
    };

    template <typename T>
    concept entity =
        can_behave<T> and
        has_hp_getter<T>
    ;
}


Meaning of the { } -> "operator" in C++
